# Div centering within another Div - left aligned?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I know this question has been asked several time before, and generally I can fix it myself, but for some reason I can not get these icons to center. They are always left aligned. If the good people of SO wouldn't mind taking a look I would be much obliged. It is probably an easy fix, I'm just overlooking something.

HTML:

```
<div class="footerSection">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 btn-toolbar">
            <span id="" class="btn btn-lg footerMainButton"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="footerInside" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">     
            <div class="divOuter col-lg-12">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 divCenter">
                    <button type="button" class="footerSave">
                        <img class="footerSvg" src="../../img/icon_disk_save.svg" alt="save" /><br /><span>Save</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 divCenter">
                    <button type="button" class="footerPreview">
                        <img class="footerSvg" src="../../img/icon_play.svg" alt="preview" /><span><br />Preview</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 divCenter">
                    <button type="button" class="footerDelete">
                        <img class="footerSvg" src="../../img/icon_trash.svg" alt="delete" /><br /><span>Delete</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 divCenter">
                    <button type="button" class="footerView">
                        <img class="footerSvg" src="../../img/icon_long_right_arrow.svg" alt="view" /><span><br />View/Edit</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 divCenter">
                    <button type="button" class="footerRemove">
                        <img class="footerSvg" src="../../img/icon_minus.svg" alt="remove" /><span><br />Remove</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 divCenter">
                    <button type="button" class="footerNewMedia">
                        <img class="footerSvg" src="../../img/icon_upload_arrow.svg" alt="New Media" /><span><br />New Media</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>                       
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <button type="button" class="mapMarkerStyle">
                <img style="width: 36px;height: 36px;" src="../../img/icon_map_pin_blue.svg" alt="Map Pin" /><span></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .footerSection {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #424242;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    padding: 20px 0 20px;
    bottom: 0;
}
#footerInside {
    display: block;
    float: left
}
.divOuter {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.divCenter {
    text-align: center;    
}
```

Some notes on the code. The centered icons are display none normally until called. Using display: none as to not take up space.

Comment: Maybe a fiddle so we can see what you have?

Comment: There is a fiddle below with as close as possible to the code I have, save bootstrap. I think this may be an issue with using col. Since it has a float left by default

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. It was the inside divs with the col classes that was messing this up in my code. So by removing the nested divs it sorted itself out. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes to your CSS:

```
#footerInside {
    width:  500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#footerInside div {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

**FIDDLE:**  http://jsfiddle.net/dzort1rb/

Comment: Even with these changes it still is left aligned. I am using bootstrap 3x if it helps any more. For such a simple thing it is really frustrating. I do greatly appreciate the help though.

Comment: I am going to mark this as correct, because it does work with the code supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine for me

Use `class="text-center"` in the parent `div` where you required